# How ansible can call multiple files under path option as a variable

Tags: linux, ansible

I am just learning ansible and trying to understand how can i include multiple file in the path `option` in ansible `replace` module.

I have three files where i need to replace a `old hostname` with `new hostanme`.

### Files are :

```
 - /etc/hosts
 - /etc/hosts.custom
 - /etc/hosts-backup
```

## Below Simple Play works fine:

```
- name: Replace string in hosts file
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Replace string in host file
      replace:
        path: /etc/hosts
        regexp: "171.20.20.16   fostrain.example.com"
        replace: "171.20.20.16   dbfoxtrain.example.com"
        backup: yes
```

However, after lot of googling i see this can be done as follows, but in case i have multiple files and those needs to be called as a variable in different modules, How we can define then in such a way so as to call them by variable name.

### Below is Just what i am trying to understand..

```
- name: Replace string in hosts file
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Checking file contents
      slurp:
        path: "{{ ?? }}"  <-- How to check these three files here
      register: fileCheck.out

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ (fileCheck.out.content | b64decode).split('\n') }}"

    - name: Replace string in host file
      replace:
        path: "{{ item.path }}"
        regexp: "{{ item:from }}"
        replace: "{{ item:to }}"
        backup: yes
     loop:
       - { path: "/etc/hosts", From: "171.20.20.16   fostrain.example.com", To: "171.20.20.16   dbfoxtrain.example.com"}
       - { Path: "/etc/hosts.custom", From: "171.20.20.16   fostrain.example.com", To: "171.20.20.16   dbfoxtrain.example.com"}
       - { Path: "/etc/hosts-backup", From: "171.20.20.16   fostrain.example.com", To: "171.20.20.16   dbfoxtrain.example.com"}
```

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create couple of variables; a list with all the files, from and to replacement strings or divide them by ip and domain. Then loop over all the files using the file list variable and use from and to replacement variables for each file. If multiple ip and domain mapping is required then you need to adjust the structure further. So recommend going through ansible documentation on [using variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html) and [loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html) for more details.

Playbook may look like below. Have used a minor regex and you can adjust as required.

```yaml
- name: Replace string in hosts file
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    files:
      - /etc/hosts
      - /etc/hosts.custom
      - /etc/hosts-backup
    from_ip: "171.20.20.16"
    from_dn: "fostrain.example.com"
    to_ip: "171.20.20.16"
    to_dn: "dbfoxtrain.example.com"
  tasks:
    - name: Replace string in host file
      replace:
        path: "{{ item }}"
        regexp: "{{ from_ip }}\\s+{{ from_dn }}"
        replace: "{{ to_ip }} {{ to_dn }}"
      loop: "{{ files }}"
```

If you want to see the contents of each file then `slurp` and `debug` modules can be used like below:

```yaml
    - slurp:
        path: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ files }}"
      register: contents
    
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ (item.content | b64decode).split('\n') }}"
      loop: "{{ contents.results }}"
```

Comment: @. Moon, thank you for the solution, +1, In case i have two more variables like `from_ip` and `to_ip`  , lets suppose values are `from_ip: "192.168.12.22" ` and `to_ip: "192.168.13.22"` then how that can be done, sorry for asking too much.

Comment: Have updated the answer. Would also recommend to go through ansible documentation to understand the usage better.